# How to Referesh ImageButton by different language

Tags: android

[image]I have one textview (Language) and two radio buttons (chinese) and (English) and a save button, in the same layout. My problem is after choosing a language, when i click on the save button my textview (Language) changes accordingly but my button (save) does not get refreshed.

my code is:

```
 if (lang_selected.equalsIgnoreCase("English")) {
        Locale locale = new Locale("es");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale; 
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        //initView(view);

    }else if(lang_selected.equalsIgnoreCase("Chinese")){
        Locale locale = new Locale("zh");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale; 
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        //initView(view);
    }
```

here i am trying to refresh my textview text and Imagebutton :

```
 txtLanguage_onLanguageScreen.setText(getString(R.string.language));
    saveBtnlanguage.setImageResource(R.drawable.general_info_save_button);
```

Comment: So, the problem is that the image doesn't change to the Chinese flag?

Comment: yes, but there is ImageButton instead of image

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that the image doesn't change to the Chinese flag, then
you have to provide localized drawable folders.
i.e.: **drawable-zh** for Chinese graphic resources.

If you are supporting multiple resolutions, you also have to add the dpi:
i.e.: **drawable-zh-xhdpi** for xhdpi (~320 dpi) resources

HERE you put your Chinese flag, while in drawable (drawable-xhdpi) you put the English flag.
Because English is the **default** language, so it's not needed to specify "en".

AND your **values.zh** folder, containing the file strings.xml (that I assume you're using, since the rest works), should contain the Chinese version of "Save" in a string called "language" (the same you use for the English version)

After all, a deep read of [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Provide a chinese version of the text "Save" in your values folder. Create a folder values-zh and provide string.xml for the chinese language.